# Adicionar campo input a cada vez que função é chamada

Tags: php, javascript, input

Tenho um módulo em um sistema ao qual estou desenvolvendo, onde, a cada clique em <kbd>inserir</kbd>, o usuário clica sobre uma foto e é adicionado uma marcação sobre o exato local do clique.

Preciso que a cada clique sobre a imagem, seja criado um `input` para que o usuário digite o que representa o local do clique, para que eu possa guardar no meu banco.

**Código da view:**

```
<div class="area-imagem">
  <img src="<?= $img?>" alt="<?= $img?>" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="area-opcoes">
  <button type="button" id="marcar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="marcar()">Inserir Marcação</button>
  <button type="button" id="desmarcar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="desmarcar()">Desfazer Marcação</button>
</div>
```

**Código Javascript:**

```
function marcar(){
    document.querySelector(".area-imagem").addEventListener("click", evento);
}

var count = 0;
var marc = 0;
function evento(){
    count++;
    marc++;
    var pos = handler(event);
    var pixel = "<div class=\"pixel\" id=\"marc"+marc+"\" name=\"marc"+marc+"\" style=\"top: " + (pos.y - this.offsetTop) + "px; left: " + (pos.x - this.offsetLeft) + "px;\">" + count + "</div>";

    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + pixel;
    this.removeEventListener('click', evento); // remove o event listener
}

function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var pageX = e.pageX;
    var pageY = e.pageY;

    // IE 8
    if (pageX === undefined) {
        pageX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        pageY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

   return {x: pageX, y: pageY};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de concatenar `.innerHTML` com `.innerHTML`, seria melhor criar as divs com `.createElement`. Assim você consegue inserir um input em cada div mantendo o que foi digitado nos que já foram criados.

Nos inputs coloquei `name="marcas[]"` para que você possa recebê-los em forma de array ao enviar.

Veja no exemplo abaixo as modificações que fiz criando elementos:

```js
function marcar(){
    document.querySelector(".area-imagem").addEventListener("click", evento);
}

var count = 0;
var marc = 0;
function evento(){
   count++;
   marc++;
   var pos = handler(event);
   var pixel = document.createElement("div");
   pixel.className = "pixel";
   pixel.id = "marc"+marc;
   pixel.style = "top: " + (pos.y - this.offsetTop) + "px; left: " + (pos.x - this.offsetLeft) + "px;";
   pixel.textContent = count;

   this.appendChild(pixel);
   
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.name = "marcas[]";
   document.getElementById("marc"+marc).appendChild(input);
   input.focus();
   
   var input_hidden = document.createElement("input");
   input_hidden.name = "coords[]";
   input_hidden.type = "hidden";
   input_hidden.value = (pos.x - this.offsetLeft)+"x"+ (pos.y - this.offsetTop);
   document.getElementById("marc"+marc).appendChild(input_hidden);
   
   this.removeEventListener('click', evento); // remove o event listener
}

function handler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var pageX = e.pageX;
    var pageY = e.pageY;

    // IE 8
    if (pageX === undefined) {
        pageX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        pageY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

   return {x: pageX, y: pageY};
}
```

```css
.area-imagem img{
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-imagem">
  <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="<?= $img?>" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="area-opcoes">
  <button type="button" id="marcar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="marcar()">Inserir Marcação</button>
  <button type="button" id="desmarcar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="desmarcar()">Desfazer Marcação</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Sam, realmente funcionou. Só mais uma dúvida, no caso para eu registrar os valores das coordenadas + as descrições dos pontos, como faço para enviar esses dados por metodo POST, eu não precisaria que esses elementos estivessem dentro de uma tag FORM?

Comment: Sim, precisa estar tudo dentro de um form. Agora, para enviar as coordenadas junto, vc teria que criar inputs e colocar elas dentro. Acho que inputs hidden resolveria e vc coloca nelas as coordenadas num padrão, que poderia ser, por exemplo, 120x170. Quando vc receber esse input no backend, vc quebra pelo "x" onde o primeiro valor é o eixo X e o segundo o eixo Y.

Comment: Muito obrigado, farei este procedimento, qualquer dúvida eu aviso.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta o código pra criar o input hidden.

Comment: Muito obrigado, se conseguisse votaria 1000x como útil. Agora vou prosseguir com a recuperação dos dados pelo backend.